# Formik validate initial values on page load

Tags: reactjs, formik

Code below validate when submit and onFocusOut of textbox fine, What I expect it to trigger validation first reload of the page with initial values.

Tried `validateOnMount`, as well as others but not worked.

Whats missing here?

```
const RoleValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    Adi: Yup.string()
        .min(2, "En az 2 karakter olmalıdır")
        .max(30, "En fazla 30 karakter olmalıdır")
        .required("Gerekli!")
})


const Role = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Formik
                onSubmit={(values, { validate }) => {
                    debugger
                    validate(values);
                    alert("Submietted!")
                    props.handleFormSubmit()
                }}
                initialValues={{
                    Adi: "d"
                }}
                validationSchema={RoleValidationSchema}
                validateOnMount={true}
                validateOnChange={true}
                validateOnBlur={true}
                render={({ errors, touched, setFieldValue, ...rest }) => {
                    debugger
                    return (
                        <Form>
                            <Row>
                                <Col sm="12">
                                    <Label for="Adi">Rol Adi</Label>
                                    <FormGroup className="position-relative">
                                        <Field
                                            autoComplete="off"
                                            id="Adi"
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="Adi"
                                            type="text"
                                        />
                                        <ErrorMessage name="Adi">
                                            {(msg) => (
                                                <div className="field-error text-danger">{msg}</div>
                                            )}
                                        </ErrorMessage>
                                    </FormGroup>

                                </Col>
                                <Tree dataSource={treeData} targetKeys={targetKeys} expandKeys={[]} onChange={onChange} />
                            </Row>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" > Kaydet</button>
                        </Form>
                    )
                }}
            />

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me to show validation error on form load.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (formRef.current) {
      formRef.current.validateForm()
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to provide a initial value for validation in the "initialIsValid" prop.

```
const validationSchema= Yup.object()
const initialValues = { ... }
const initialIsValid = schema.isValidSync(initialValues)

return <Formik 
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          initialIsValid={initialIsValid }
          ...
       >
          ...
       </Formik>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add enableReinitialize Prop to your Formik Component

```
<Formik
   enableReinitialize
   ......
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit specific case with dynamic Yup schema. Schema was generated based on API data. And `validateOnMount` was failing as when component was mounted there was no schema yet (API response not received yet).
I end up with something like this.

Inside component I used `useEffect`. Notice: I used `useRef` to be able to reference Formik outside of form.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (formRef.current) {
    // check that schema was generated based on API response
    if(Object.keys(dynamicValidationSchema).length != 0){
        formRef.current.validateForm()
    }
  }
}, [initialData, dynamicValidationSchema])
```

Formik:

```
    <Formik
        innerRef={formRef}
        enableReinitialize
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}
    >
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found is to explicitly add `initialErrors={{..}}` to Formik.

In the below example, it's added depending on some condition. Unfortunately that duplicates the Yup validation/message which I also have in the schema. Nothing else worked, no `validateOnMount` or anything else.

```
    <Formik 
        enableReinitialize
        validationSchema={schema} 
        onSubmit={ (values) => {
            submitForm(values);
        }}
        initialValues={initialFormValues}
        /* Unfortunately a duplication of Yup Schema validation on this field,
           but can't force Formik/Yup to validate initially */
        initialErrors={!isEmptyObject(initialFormValues) && 
                       initialFormValues.inactiveApproverCondition && 
                       {'approverId': 'Selected Approver is no longer eligible. Please choose a different Approver to continue.'}}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try updating your code follow this

```
render={({ errors, touched, setFieldValue, isValid, ...rest })
```

and

```
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" disabled={!isValid}> Kaydet</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me, was to call focus and blur on the first input text in the form. The ref to the Formik form for some reason was undefined on mount.

Since I use material-ui TextField, I call focus() and blur() on the first input field (material-ui TextField ref.current is the outer div).

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (textBoxRef.current) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        textBoxRef.current.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
        setTimeout(() => {
            textBoxRef.current.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].blur();
        }, 50);
    }, 50);
  }
}, [])
```